# Why WinForm Form.FormClosed Event Is Not Triggered From a Form Holder?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have 2 Forms, **FormA** and **FormB**. FormA is opened from FormB button clicked event. And in FormA holder, FormClosed event from FormA is registered. **The problem is if I close FormB, the FormA is closed as well but the FormClosed event is not called.**

**How to make FormClosed event is called?**
I want FormA Holder is notified when FormA is closed/closing to dispose the resources.

This is the simplified code snippet:

```
internal class FormA : Form
{
    public FormA()
    {
        this.Text = @"Form A";
    }
}

internal class FormAHolder
{
    internal FormA FormA { get; private set; }

    internal FormAHolder()
    {
        this.FormA = new FormA();
        this.FormA.FormClosed += this.OnFormAFormClosed;
    }

    private void OnFormAFormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hallo, please call me!!!");
        //// Clean up code should be here....
    }
}

internal class FormB : Form
{
    public FormB()
    {
        this.Text = @"Form B";
        var button = new Button { Text = @"Open Form A" };
        button.Click += this.OnButtonClick;
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formAHolder = new FormAHolder();
        formAHolder.FormA.Show();
    }
}

[Test]
public void FormTest()
{
    var formB = new FormB();
    formB.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Your FormA instance is never closed.  It just dies a violent death when your test runner completes, wiped out by Windows when it cleans up.  Your [Test] method is not in any way a substitute for what your Main() method does.

Comment: Ok I understand, maybe I should test it like Jens Kloster suggested.

Comment: It is never that clear to me why this kind of code needs to be tested.  What exactly are you going to do when the test fails because the event doesn't fire?  Are you going to fix the .NET Framework?  You really only ever test the test code.  FormAHolder is *very* ugly.

Comment: FormHolder in real software is provider of 2 kind of forms for applications, one is RibbonForm and the other is Toolbar based form. Because some users like Ribbon and the other like Toolbar form.
The unit test is used to test why in a certain application doesn't call Dispose method? And I realize that my unit test is not good because I didn't know about the behavior of Form.

Comment: What I want to know is, I want Dispose method of FormA is called if FormB is closed. That's all. FormB are from several application and the problem is with WPF application will not call Dispose. I don't want Applications (FormB) to call explicitly Dispose. I have read about finalizer but it will not 100% guaranty to be called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start FormB with a message loop.
use this:

```
 Application.Run(new FormB());
```

instead of

```
var formB = new FormB();
formB.ShowDialog();
```

[Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does exacly that, but you can only call it once pr. `Thread`.

Comment: Yes, that works, but FormB is actually WPF form application. Is that work as well? I have not tested yet.

Comment: hmmm upon futher inpection, im not sure.. the first time you start a WinForms Form (in a new Thread) you could use `Application.Run`

Comment: :-(, no the WPF application has the same effect with that unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the cleanup code from the FormB `Closed` event, by extracting the cleanup code to a method in class `FormAHolder` and calling it when you need to.

Comment: The Problem is FormA is used by many application like FormB. It is more convenience if FormA component can clean their own stuffs.